# Finding the equation of electric field lines.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

Say we have a stationary particle located at $(0,0)$ with a positive unit charge, and a stationary particle located at $(a,0)$ with charge a negative unit charge. I want to find the field lines associated with the force field generated by the two charges.

Suppose we have a charge with positive unit charge located at $(x_0,y_0)$. The force acting on this charge can be described with the following (disgusting) vector:
$$\left(\frac{x_0}{\left(x_0^2+y_0^2\right)^{3/2}}+\frac{a-x_0}{\left((x_0-a)^2+y_0^2\right)^{3/2}},\frac{y_0}{\left(x_0^2+y_0^2\right)^{3/2}}-\frac{y_0}{\left((x_0-a)^2+y_0^2\right)^{3/2}}\right)$$
This yields the following (disgusting) differetial-equation for the field lines associated with the force field:
$$y'\left(\frac{x}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{3/2}}+\frac{a-x}{\left((x-a)^2+y^2\right)^{3/2}}\right)=\frac{y}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{3/2}}-\frac{y}{\left((x-a)^2+y^2\right)^{3/2}}$$
I can sort of simplify (but not really):
$$y'\left(x\left((x-a)^2+y^2\right)^{3/2}+(a-x)\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{3/2}\right)=y\left(\left((x-a)^2+y^2\right)^{3/2}-\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{3/2}\right)$$
Unfortunately I have no idea how to solve this thing. Any help would be very much appreciated.

I have posted the exact same question on [physics.stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/323916/finding-the-equation-of-electric-field-lines)

Update: doing the same thing in polar coordinates yields the following differential equation (I think).
$$\frac{\frac{dr}{d\theta}\sin\theta+r\cos\theta}{\frac{dr}{d\theta}\cos\theta-r\sin\theta}\left(\frac{\cos\theta}{r^2}+\frac{1}{\left(r^2\sin^2\theta+\left(a-r\cos\theta\right)^2\right)\sqrt{\left(\left(\frac{r\sin\theta}{a-r\cos\theta}\right)^2+1\right)}}\right)=\frac{\sin\theta}{r^2}-\frac{r\sin\theta}{\left(a-r\cos\theta\right)\left(r^2\sin^2\theta+\left(a-r\cos\theta\right)^2\right)\sqrt{\left(\left(\frac{r\sin\theta}{a-r\cos\theta}\right)^2+1\right)}}$$
I think the above only works for points whose $x$-coordinate is less than $a$.

Comment: I've asked to Wolfram Alpha and the answer is annoying. The dipole is a recurring illustration in the electricity topic and I've never seen the equation for the field lines, only nice drawings. It's understandable why. Maybe there is some more easily tractable in the limit $a\to 0$

Comment: This problem just ***begs*** to be considered in [elliptic coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_coordinate_system).

Comment: I've found a solution on pages 8 and 9 in this book: https://archive.org/details/StaticAndDynamicElectricity